# htaccess Secure Redirect

Tags: ssl, redirect

The goal is to have **every page** (minus one folder) of a site **redirect to https**. I've discovered the following **does not** do that. The one folder contains a subdomain. Let's call it mahogany.com.

**Edit: Modify rules**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site1\.mobi [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site1\.mobi [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mahogany\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

If someone types `site1.mobi` or `www.site1.mobi` into their browser, apache with the above in the document root htaccess will not redirect.

What is wrong with the above? Is a line for mahogany.com needed to exclude it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default logical operator for `RewriteCond` is "and"; the `HTTP_HOST` can't be both of those so the condition will never be satisfied.

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site1\.mobi$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site1\.mobi$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Also, you mentioned a directory exception, but I don't see one in there.  You can add one with an extra `RewriteCond` or by changing your `RewriteRule` condition:

```
RewriteRule ^excepted/location/.* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Shane. Trying it out now. Did you forget `(` & `)` in the line 4 of the first code? Originally it was `(.*)`

Comment: What about adding this condition: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mahogany.com [NC]` and adding `,OR` to the previous rule?

Comment: @DavidC No, I didn't forget them; you weren't using them so I removed them.  And yes, adding that and adding `OR` to the other hostname will make it apply to all 3 of those hostnames.